# How to interrupt select call on windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, sockets, select

I know it's probably a basic question, but I'd like to hear the best way to realize it.

So to the problem. I have a driver thread using a call to select, and I have a GUI thread that needs sometimes to interrupt select by writing to some file descriptor within the same process (GUI FD or something). I used pipe in UNIX, but I'm not experienced in sockets for Windows, so I'm not sure what kind of FD I should use. Example is greatly appreciated but not required ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`select()` is not the best to implement asynchronous I/O under Windows. unfortunately, the `select()` call on windows only works with socket handles and not with pipe or fie handles.

you should have a look at [overlapped I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740087%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

by using an event in your overlapped structure, you can have a behaviour close to `select()`. any event on a socket will trigger an event, which you can wait on by using `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. now, your GUI thread can signal the I/O thread by setting a specific (separate) event, which you create using the `CreateEvent()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the timeout shorter on the select and then loop round if it was a timeout.  Or you could send a simple packet to the socket being selected causing it to wake up.